Bool being reset when navigating between screens
I am trying to create a radio player app with flutter. This app only has 2 screens which are accessible via the BottomNavigationBar (in this case GNav).
When I start listening to the radio, the Play-Button becomes a Pause-Button. Now when switching screens via the BottomNavBar and then again back to the player, the running radio player now has a Play-Button instead of a expected Pause-Button, since the audio is still playing.
When I start listening to the radio, the Play-Button becomes a Pause-Button. Now when switching screens via the BottomNavBar and then again back to the player, the running radio player now has a Play-Button instead of a expected Pause-Button, since the audio is still playing.
I am pretty sure that the bool isPlaying = false; is being called every time I switch screens.
What can I do so that the bool isPlaying does not get reset to 'false' every time i come back to the player?
main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:radio_orient/components/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:radio_orient/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:radio_orient/pages/more_info.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(RadioApp());
}

class RadioApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioAppState createState() => _RadioAppState();
}

class _RadioAppState extends State<RadioApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void navigateBottomBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _pages = [Home(), const MoreInfo()];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Radio Orient'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 120, 85),
        ),
        body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(207, 185, 151, 1),
        bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavBar(
          onTabChange: (index) => navigateBottomBar(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


home.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:radio_player/radio_player.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  RadioPlayer _radioPlayer = RadioPlayer();
  List<String>? metadata;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  void initRadioPlayer() {
    _radioPlayer.setChannel(
      title: 'My Radio',
      url:
          'https://myradio.url',
      imagePath: 'assets/radio.jpg',
    );

    _radioPlayer.stateStream.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = value;
      });
    });

    _radioPlayer.metadataStream.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        metadata = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initRadioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _radioPlayer.getArtworkImage(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              Image artwork;
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                artwork = snapshot.data;
              } else {
                artwork = Image.asset(
                  'assets/radio.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                );
              }
              return SizedBox(
                height: 180,
                width: 180,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  child: artwork,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text(
            'Radio Orient Live',
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
          ),
          Text(
            metadata?[1] ?? '',
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              isPlaying ? _radioPlayer.pause() : _radioPlayer.play();
            },
            tooltip: 'Control button',
            child: Icon(
              isPlaying ? Icons.pause_rounded : Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

bottom_nav_bar.dart:
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart";

class MyBottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  void Function(int)? onTabChange;
  MyBottomNavBar({super.key, required this.onTabChange});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: GNav(
        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
        activeColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
        tabActiveBorder: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        tabBorderRadius: 16,
        onTabChange: (value) => onTabChange!(value),
        tabs: [
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.home,
            text: 'Start',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.info,
            text: 'Info',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Welcome to SO!
It seems like havent directly asked a question (but rather just said "expected xyz"). Can you please [edit] your question to include what your trying to ask?

@MendelG done. thanks.

Shouldn't variable isPlaying  be declared within _RadioAppState class which I'm guessing is the main class of your application instead of _HomeState class which I assume is class representing your home screen? Declaring it as part of home screen class might cause variable isPlaying  to be reset to its initial position every time the home screen is shown. Again since I don't have any experience working with futter or dart but instead some experience in other object oriented languages I'm just guessing here. ...

... I'm guessing you need to declare your isPlaying  variable as Global Variable in Dart

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

the problem is that when you switch your screen, the state gets removed from the tree. So to say flutter to keep alive the state you can use a mixin: AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin then your home screen would look like following:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:radio_player/radio_player.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

// add this mixin to your state definition
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  RadioPlayer _radioPlayer = RadioPlayer();
  List<String>? metadata;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  // here you say that this state should be keept alive
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  void initRadioPlayer() {
    _radioPlayer.setChannel(
      title: 'My Radio',
      url:
          'https://myradio.url',
      imagePath: 'assets/radio.jpg',
    );

    _radioPlayer.stateStream.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = value;
      });
    });

    _radioPlayer.metadataStream.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        metadata = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initRadioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _radioPlayer.getArtworkImage(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              Image artwork;
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                artwork = snapshot.data;
              } else {
                artwork = Image.asset(
                  'assets/radio.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                );
              }
              return SizedBox(
                height: 180,
                width: 180,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  child: artwork,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text(
            'Radio Orient Live',
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
          ),
          Text(
            metadata?[1] ?? '',
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              isPlaying ? _radioPlayer.pause() : _radioPlayer.play();
            },
            tooltip: 'Control button',
            child: Icon(
              isPlaying ? Icons.pause_rounded : Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

here the docs: click me
